# How to get current value of a varaible in nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How to get current value of a varaible in nuxt3 ?

when i define a `const counter = ref(0)` in nuxt3
In vue, I can use vue devtool to find it's current value.
But in Nuxt, I cannot find it.
I have try to use Nuxt devtool, but i still cannot find the varable.